# Powerpoint vba to change text gradient?

Tags: vba, text, gradient, powerpoint

Is there anything in Powerpoint vba (2007 or 2010) that lets you set or change the gradient colors on a text object (the text itself)? All I can find are presetTextEffect settings. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "text object itself?"

Comment: I was referring to textrange.text as opposed to its frame. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?...

[image]

If so, here is the code which I made it with. You will need to improve it accordingly. There are plenty of formatting possibilities when applying gradient formation. Therefore I will suggest to experiment and checking VBA help for additional information.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim TXTbox As Shape
    Set TXTbox = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)

        With TXTbox.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 128)
            .OneColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 1, 1
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed. Not sure how I missed it. I must be going blind at my old age.